# Feeding right-hand coordinate system into API which takes left-hand coordinate system

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx, rendering

I have below camera parameters in right-hand coordinate system:
CameraPosition:  (x1,x2,x3)
Camera Up Vector: (y1,y2,y3)
Camera LookAtPoint: (z1, z2, z3)

I need to feed these values to a graphic API which uses a left-handed coordinate system.( i.e. DirectX ). What will be the equivalent coordinates to feed to this graphics API. Does flipping z coordinate will do the trick? Or Z near and Z far should also be taken into account?

Comment: That depends a lot on what the library does with the data and what you want the data to represent.

Comment: DirectX is not more left handed than right handed. Since GPU use shaders, it is only a convention has long has at the end, you feed the proper projected coordinate in the unit cube. Right to left usually require a coordinate flip, and also to invert the winding order of the triangle. But everything depends mostly on your engine convention and math.